# Priority queue in Erlang

Tags: priority-queue, erlang

I'm new to Erlang and I'm trying to port my [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) solutions in C# to Erlang. I have a priority queue implementation with unit tests.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something(I probably do) if I was writing serious Erlang code.

**priority_queue.hrl**

```
-record(heap_node, { item :: any(), children :: [#heap_node{}] }).
-type heap_node() :: #heap_node{}.

-record(priority_queue, { root :: heap_node() | nil, comparer :: comparer() }).
-type priority_queue() :: #priority_queue{}.

-type comparer() :: fun((any(), any()) -> less | equal | greater).
```

**priority_queue.erl**

```
-module(priority_queue).
-export([new/1, is_empty/1, peek/1, enqueue/2, dequeue/1]).
-include_lib("priority_queue.hrl").

-spec new(comparer()) -> priority_queue().
new(Comparer) -> #priority_queue{ root = nil, comparer = Comparer}.

-spec is_empty(priority_queue()) -> true | false.
is_empty(#priority_queue{ root = nil }) -> true;
is_empty(_) -> false.

-spec peek(priority_queue()) -> {ok, any()} | error.
peek(#priority_queue{root = nil}) -> error;
peek(#priority_queue{root = #heap_node{ item = Item}}) -> {ok, Item}.

-spec createHeapNode(any()) ->heap_node().
createHeapNode(Item) -> #heap_node{ item = Item, children = []}.

-spec enqueue(any(), priority_queue()) -> priority_queue().
enqueue(Item, #priority_queue{ root = nil } = Source) -> 
  Root = createHeapNode(Item),
  Source#priority_queue{ root = Root};
enqueue(Item, #priority_queue{ root = Root, comparer =  Comparer} = Source) ->
  NewRoot = merge(Root, createHeapNode(Item), Comparer),
  Source#priority_queue{ root = NewRoot}.

-spec merge(heap_node(), heap_node(), comparer()) -> heap_node().
merge(#heap_node{ item = Item1, children = Children1} = Node1,
      #heap_node{ item = Item2, children = Children2} = Node2,
      Comparer) ->
  case Comparer(Item1, Item2) of
    less -> Node1#heap_node{ children = [Node2 | Children1]};
    _    -> Node2#heap_node{ children = [Node1 | Children2]}
  end.

-spec dequeue(priority_queue()) -> {ok, any(), priority_queue()} | error.
dequeue(#priority_queue{ root = nil }) -> error;
dequeue(#priority_queue{ root = #heap_node{ item = Item, children = Children}, comparer = Comparer } = Source) ->
  NewRoot = pair(Children, Comparer),
  {ok, Item, Source#priority_queue{ root = NewRoot} }.

-spec pair([heap_node()], comparer()) -> heap_node() | nil.
pair([], _) -> nil;
pair([HeapNode], _) -> HeapNode;
pair([HeapNode1 , HeapNode2], Comparer) -> merge(HeapNode1, HeapNode2, Comparer);
pair([HeapNode | Rest], Comparer) -> merge(HeapNode, pair(Rest, Comparer), Comparer).
```

**priority_queue_tests.erl**

```
-module(priority_queue_tests).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

is_empty_test() -> 
  Pq1 = create_new_priority_queue(),
  ?assert(priority_queue:is_empty(Pq1)),
  Pq2 = priority_queue:enqueue(5, Pq1),
  ?assertNot(priority_queue:is_empty(Pq2)).

peek_test() ->
  Pq1 = create_new_priority_queue(),
  ?assertEqual(error, priority_queue:peek(Pq1)),
  Pq2 = priority_queue:enqueue(5, Pq1),
  ?assertEqual({ok, 5}, priority_queue:peek(Pq2)).

enqueue_and_dequeue_test() ->
  Pq1 = create_new_priority_queue(),
  ?assertEqual(error, priority_queue:dequeue(Pq1)),
  Pq2 = enqueue([8, 3, 5, 4, 9, 0], Pq1),
  {Items, Pq3} = dequeue(6, Pq2),
  [0, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9] = Items,
  ?assertEqual(error, priority_queue:dequeue(Pq3)).



compare(X, X) -> equal;
compare(X, Y) when X < Y -> less;
compare(_, _) -> greater.

create_new_priority_queue() -> priority_queue:new(fun compare/2).

enqueue([], Pq) -> Pq;
enqueue([Current | Rest], Pq) -> enqueue(Rest, priority_queue:enqueue(Current, Pq)).

dequeue(Count, Pq) -> dequeue(Count, Pq, []).
dequeue(0, Pq, Acc) -> { lists:reverse(Acc), Pq};
dequeue(Count, Pq, Acc) -> 
  {ok, Current, NewPq} = priority_queue:dequeue(Pq),
  dequeue(Count-1, NewPq, [Current | Acc]).
```

A few of points I specifically want to know:

- Usage of records/types/specs
- Returning errors on peek and dequeue methods
- Pattern matching on merge and dequeue methods. They seems a bit complicated to me
- Using pattern matching for assertions in unit tests
- Having variable names like Pq1, Pq2, Pq3 and so on

I tried make it as simple as I could but if it can be improved, please let me know. Any styling tips are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The code look good for me, just one comment - not need explicit export function in test module:

```
-compile(export_all). %%<-not need
```

About your questions.

1. Better - read corresponding section of [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html)
2. Traditionally result value have form `{ok,Result} | {error,Reason}` if function not use name prefix for explicit notice(for example `is_empty` from your code)
3. Explicit the extraction looks even worse.
4. Macros `assertEqual` is provided more full information about errors. You can check it by example. For wrong match 
   pattern matching:

   ```
   13> eunit:test(priority_queue).
   priority_queue_tests: enqueue_and_dequeue_test...*failed*
   in function priority_queue_tests:enqueue_and_dequeue_test/0     (priority_queue_test
   s.erl, line 22)
   **error:{badmatch,[0,3,4,5,8,9]}
     output:<<"">>
   ...
   ```

   assertEqual macros:

   ```
   17> eunit:test(priority_queue).
   priority_queue_tests: enqueue_and_dequeue_test...*failed*
   in function priority_queue_tests:'-enqueue_and_dequeue_test/0-fun-1-'/2 (priorit
   y_queue_tests.erl, line 24)
   in call from priority_queue_tests:enqueue_and_dequeue_test/0 (priority_queue_tes
   ts.erl, line 24)
   **error:{assertEqual,[{module,priority_queue_tests},
                 {line,24},
                 {expression,"Items"},
                 {expected,[0,3,4,5,1,9]},
                 {value,[0,3,4,5,8,9]}]}
     output:<<"">>
   ...
   ```
5. Leave a link to a detailed [answer in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39339239#39339239) (thanks @zxq9).